# "Ich wusste es!"

Tags: usage, phrase

Eine bei vielen Menschen häufig anzutreffende Reaktion auf die Bewahrheitung ihrer Vermutungen ist "Ich wusste es!". Dabei kann es sich hier doch offensichtlich nicht um Wissen handeln, da sich sonst der Ausruf der Gewissheit erübrigen würde. Schließlich impliziert "Wissen" die Selbstsicherheit über die Zuverlässigkeit der eigenen Kenntnisse, d. h., das eingetretene Ereignis hätte erwartet worden sein müssen und somit die Erregung ausbleiben. Nichtsdestotrotz zeigt die Emotionalität der Äußerung, dass Unsicherheit bestand. Entsprechend ist die eigene Bestätigung durch "Ich wusste es!" unzulässig, sondern sollte besser mit "Ich habe es geahnt!" geäußert werden, oder nicht?

Comment: *Offensichtlich … schließlich … bestand … ist unzulässig … sollte geäußert werden*. Reicht da ein kleines „oder nicht?“, um eine Kette von Behauptungen und Forderungen noch in eine Frage umzubiegen?

Comment: Sind meine Schlussfolgerungen nachvollziehbar oder irre ich mich bei meinen "Forderungen und Behauptungen"?

Comment: @Loong Mir ist bewusst, dass einem "d. h." für gewöhnlich ein Komma folgt, allerdings habe ich bewusst aus kosmetischen Gründen darauf verzichtet. Es sieht einfach scheußlich aus - meiner Meinung nach.

Comment: Du kannst Änderungen rückgängig machen („rollback“). Die Schreibung ohne Komma widerspricht auch nicht den Regeln: _Bei formelhaften Nebensätzen kann man das Komma weglassen._ (§ 76 AR)

Comment: Auch das ist mir bewusst, nur wünsche ich keinen Edit-War mit dem Moderator anzufangen. :-D (Was ist "AR"?)

Comment: [Amtliche Regelung](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf). Wobei ich inzwischen zu der Einsicht gekommen bin, daß kein (verkürzter) Nebensatz vorliegt, aber § 77(4) enthält Beispiele mit _das heißt_ ohne Komma danach.

Comment: @chrmaxggr Ein einmaliger _Rollback_ ist noch kein _Edit-War_. Und ob jemand Moderator ist oder nicht, spielt bei solchen Änderungen keine Rolle.

Answer (score 2):

"Ich wusste es!" wird aber auch häufig gesagt, wenn man etwas wirklich besser wusste, sich aber durch Unsicherheiten zu einer gegensätzlichen Handlung entschieden hat. Stellt sich nun im Nachhinein heraus, dass die erste Überlegung doch richtig war und man sich nicht durch seine Unsicherheit/Angst hätte anders entscheiden dürfen, so passt der Ausspruch "Ich wusste es!", was eine Kurzform für "Ich wusste es besser und habe doch ... gemacht, verdammt!"

Comment: Ich denke, auch hier ist im Wesentlichen das gleiche Problem wie oben am Werk, nämlich sprachliche Ungenauigkeit bzw. eine falsche Verknüpfung von Symbol und Begriff: "wissen" ist, was den Begriffsradius angeht, einfach zu sehr auf "gesicherte Informationen" beschränkt, d. h., in deinem Fall würde ich sprachlogisch eher zu "Hätte ich besser nur ..." tendieren, auch wenn dein Vorschlag idiomatisch einwandfrei und für jedermann ebenso verständlich ist.

Answer (score 0):

Viele Menschen sagen "Ich wusste es" nicht nur, um sich selbst damit auf die Schulter zu klopfen, sondern auch, um anderen explizit auf die Nase zu binden, dass sie es gewusst haben. Ich hab es schon sehr oft erlebt, dass dieser Satz gesagt worden ist, damit auch jeder im Raum weiß, dass derjenige, der diesen Satz sagt, etwas wusste. Viele Menschen wollen nicht nur Recht haben, sondern auch Recht bekommen, und wollen, dass andere wissen, was man selbst alles so tolles weiß. (Egal ob man sich vorher 99%ig oder 100%ig sicher war. Viele Menschen sagen auch "Ich wusste es", wenn sie etwas vermutet haben, nur allein weil sie den Verdacht hatten, dass das richtig sein könnte.

Es gibt Menschen, die sind dann eher gelassener und kommentieren das nicht groß, wenn sie Sachen auch schon vorher wussten, das bekommt man dann eben auch nicht mit. Es gibt aber auch viele Menschen, die da, wie du selbst sagst, emotionaler sind und das nochmal betonen, dass sie das ja auch wussten. Das ist menschlich. Man könnte nach diesem Prinzip auch andere Emotionen hinterfragen, da in quasi jeder Situation, in der man Emotionen zeigt, gefragt werden kann "Warum zeigst du Emotionen und nimmst das, was du siehst, hörst, etc. nicht einfach ganz sachlich so hin, wie es objektiv ist?". (Es ist für viele Menschen schwer, Dinge objektiv zu sehen und Emotionen abzustellen, klar, aber man könnte diese Frage immer stellen.) Wenn du das nächste mal ein "Ich wusste es" hörst, stell doch einfach mal genau diese Frage :-)

Comment: Die Sachverhalte, die du schilderst, sind für mich voll nachvollziehbar, doch die Situation, die ich skizzierte, beschrieb in erster Linie die Bewahrheitung einer Vermutung und nicht den Drang, sich selbst aufgrund überragender Geistesleistungen über andere zu erheben. Mir geht es hier im Wesentlichen um den Erlebnisvorgang, der, so glaube ich, in einer sprachlich falschen Entscheidung mündet.

Comment: Der zum Ausdruck gebrachte Erlebnisvorgang und dessen sprachliche Äußerung hängen aus meiner Sicht eng zusammen.

Ok, ob die daraus resultierende sprachliche Entscheidung, zu sagen "Ich wusste es", richtig ist, hängt natürlich davon ab, ob man es tatsächlich wusste, und vielleicht nur nicht dazu kam, es zu vorher zu sagen. Ich denke viele Menschen achten nicht genau darauf, was sie sagen, bzw. wie sie etwas formulieren, und ob das sprachlich letztendlich falsch oder richtig ist. Vielen Menschen ist das (leider) auch eher egal, und achten auf ihre genauen Äußerungen dann nicht so, wie du z. B.

Answer (score 0):

> Erlebnisvorgang, der, so glaube ich, in einer sprachlich falschen Entscheidung mündet.

Ich möchte kurz vorwegschicken, dass Sprache immer etwas bewegliches, auslegbares, ja ausdrücklich emotional zu Verwendendes ist, denn wozu dient sie sonst, als der Kommunikation von einem wahrnehmenden Wesen zum anderen? Selbst wenn man ein großer Verfechter förmlicher Korrektheit ist, sollte man sich nicht dazu verleiten lassen, Labels wie "falsch" auf Ausdrücke zu pressen, die nur ein wenig von der zentralsten, gebräuchlichsten Bedeutung ihrer Worte abweichen. Damit erzeugt man meist nur Missverständnisse.

Ich glaube, hinter dieser scheinbar "falschen" Verwendung steht eher eine Unsicherheit des Sprechers. Die ungewöhnliche Verwendung der Worte ist nur eine Folge davon.

Und zwar ist es ja so, dass wir in jedem gegebenen Moment nicht sicher wissen können, was in der Zukunft passiert. Wir können Vorstellungen, Vermutungen, Einschätzungen haben, und wir können uns ihrer sehr sicher sein. Aber was ist *sicher* an der Stelle? Nur ein Gefühl. Fühlen wir uns sicher, weil wir uns ein bestimmtes Ereignis sehr wünschen, Geld darauf gewettet haben, und den Göttern geopfert? Oder weil unsere Erfahrung sagt, wir haben das schon 99-mal gesehen, dann wird es jetzt auch ein hundertstes Mal geschehen? Dieses Gefühl von *sicher* beinhaltet viel Spannung, denn in beiden Fällen könnte doch auch was anderes passieren. Außer wir haben wirklich eine Vorsehung.

Ich glaube, das eingangs zitierte

> Ich wusste es!!

wird nur in solchen Fällen gesagt, wenn das Eintreten des geahnten/gewünschten Ereignisses einen Wunsch befriedigt, entweder den, dass Ereignis X wirklich eintritt, oder den, dass wir gern in der Lage wären, aufgrund unserer Erfahrungen die Zukunft vorherzusagen. Es dient dem Ausdruck dessen, dass wir einen starken emotionalen Bezug zu Ereignis X hatten, dass wir dem Zeitpunkt der Entscheidung entgegengefiebert hatten. (Also auch, wenn wir Ereignis X für ein Worst-Case-Szenario hielten, an das wir immer wieder denken mussten.) Und du hast Recht: in dem dritten Fall, nämlich wenn wir durch tatsächliche Vorsehung die Zukunft gesehen hätten, würden wir uns überhaupt nicht bemüßigt fühlen, Ereignis X groß zu kommentieren.

Ich meine, dass es keine Frage der unwissenden oder falschen Verwendung von Sprache ist, sondern eher ein kreatives Nutzen der Gewissheit, die in dem Wort *wissen* mitschwingt, um die Stärke der eigenen Emotionen auszudrücken.